# How can I change user email in Firebase auth for C#

Tags: c#, uwp, firebase-authentication

As seen in the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=pt-br#set_a_users_email_address), it should be pretty easy. But in C# there's no 'updateEmail' or 'updateUser' function or anything like that.

I tried the following

```
string newEmail = "test@example.com"
var user = await authProvider.GetUserAsync(FirebaseAuthLink);
user.Email = newEmail;
```

But it does nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas? Or is it impossible to do this in C#?

Comment: What library/SDK are you using to access Firebase? A link would be most useful.

Comment: I'm using the library from Set up labs ~> https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their list of [supported use-cases](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet#supported-scenarios) and scanning the [source code](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet/blob/master/src/Firebase.Auth/FirebaseAuthProvider.cs) is seems that changing a user's email address is not supported in the [`firebase-authentication-dotnet` library](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet) at the moment.

I'd recommend filing a feature request on the repo, or adding support for it yourself and submitting a PR.